# code generating /proc file system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, proc, system-calls

In my assignment, I have added "casper" flag to task descriptor and it takes only 0, 1, 2 and 3 (default 0). I asked to "modify the code that generates the /proc filesystem so that its behavior is according to the value of the casper flag" as defined in assignment. I could not find which code in linux-source/fs/proc to be modified. Development environment: Lubuntu 14.04 LTS, Linux Kernel version 3.13.00. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208820/is-proc-directory-generated-dynamically-per-request